# mysql query get data from table b if not exist in table a

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, group and user. I want to get id of username='rahim' from sql table. If username='rahim' exist in table group, then get id from table group. Else if exist in table user, then get id from table user.

Table user

```
user_id|username
1      |rahim
2      |hemala
```

Table group

```
uid    |group_name
1      |A
2      |B
```

Query

```
SELECT 
EXISTS(select * from user where username='rahim') as user_id,
EXISTS(select * from `group` where group_name='rahim') as group_id
```

result:

```
user_id | group_id
      1 |        0
```

If exist, it show 1. This `1` refer to existence. `1:exist , 0:not exist` .  I want to filter the columns which is equal to 1 only and show id of the user which is also 1.

Expected result:

```
user_id 
    1
```

This `1` refer to id.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us some sample data from this two tables ?

Comment: @VBoka, I have added to post.

Comment: Great, please add expected result from this example data because you have a result and then you say "I want to filter the columns which is equal to one only." Please add your final result ? Cheers!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @VBoka, I have added expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IF() function returns a value if a condition is TRUE, or another value if a condition is FALSE.

```
IF(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

this query get you the id

```
SELECT IF(user_id IS NULL , group_id, user_id) as id from (
    SELECT 
    (select id from user where username='rahim') as user_id, 
    (select uid from group where group_name='rahim') as group_id
    ) as temp
```

Answer (score 1):

How about listing the values that are `1`?

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', 
                 (CASE WHEN EXISTS (select 1 from user where username = 'rahim') THEN 'USER' END),
                 (CASE WHEN EXISTS (select 1 from `group` where group_name = 'rahim') THEN 'GROUP' END)
                )
```

As for only selecting columns that have a `1` -- you cannot do that with a single query because a query returns a fixed set of columns.  What you can do (as above) is return a value that has the column names you are looking for.

Comment: I ammended THEN part of the code :`SELECT
 CONCAT_WS(
  ',',
  (
   CASE
  WHEN EXISTS(
   SELECT
    1
   FROM
    user
   WHERE
    username = 'hemala'
  )THEN
   (
    SELECT
     user_id
    FROM
     user
    WHERE
     username = 'hemala'
   )
  END
  ),
  (
   CASE
  WHEN EXISTS(
   SELECT
    1
   FROM
    groups
   WHERE
    group_name = 'hemala'
  )THEN
   (
    SELECT
     uid
    FROM
     groups
    WHERE
     group_name = 'hemala'
   )
  END
  )
 )AS id`. It gave me desire output, id of username or groupname

Comment: @Premlatha . . . If this answers your question, you should consider accepting the answer.  If another is a better answer, then you should accept that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION ALL` with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select uid from `group` 
where group_name = 'rahim'
union all
select user_id from `user` 
where username = 'rahim'
and not exists (select 1 from `group` where group_name = 'rahim')
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/55XAzPyyo1iqhXVtjeRgHU/1).
Results:

```
| uid     |
| ------- |
| 1       |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from (select case when 'rahim'=(select username from user1 where username='rahim') then 1 else 0 
end as user_id,
case when 'rahim'=(select group_name  from group1 where group_name ='rahim') then 1 else 0 
end as group_id)t; --Here you can put the filtration condition.
```